# What is the purpose of a window well for a window that is above grade?

Tags: basement, windows

Recently my neighbour installed window wells around all of his basement windows, but they all sit with the bottom edge about 2 inches above the ground. Do window wells serve a purpose if your window is still above the ground?

Comment: A window which was 0.1" above grade (with no window well) would be prone to rot from water infiltration, and from having snow sit against it.  I don't think being 2" above grade is high enough to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you were in a really dry region, it *might* be overkill, but window wells and covers also help protect basement windows from physical damage (stuff the mower throws, ornery pets, etc).

That said, two inches isn't *terribly* much, and installing them would probably be prudent if you planned to raise the grade around the window with flower beds or something.

I'm pretty sure you're wondering if installing them on your home would also be a good idea. If you've never had a problem, then you probably won't. It's worth asking your neighbor about, if they were installed as a requirement for a home inspection, it'd be nice to know.